# AWS SAM to deploy python code from a gitlab endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, sam

I have my code in a gitlab repo say https://gitlab.com/projectk. I want to deploy Dev branch code of this repo as a Lambda in AWS. I have been able to deploy Lambda from the current repository in which my gitlab-ci file is present. But I need to deploy multiple lambdas from different repos by running a common gitlab-ci file. I would like to know ho we can refer to other repos to create lambda from a common project which will be used to create AWS services.

Comment: Have you considered using GitLab's [`include:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#includeproject) feature?